# Getting Font Size of NSAttributed string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring, uifont

I'm trying to get the font size of an `NSAttributedString`, however, I'm having trouble doing this.
How do you get the font size of an `NSAttributedString` in `objective-c`?

Comment: What have you tried and in what way did it not work (add the details to question)? That will help people help you.

Comment: @CRD Reading the Q, your comment is correct. But with attributed strings it is really hard to find a first pointer. `NSAttributedString` does not define any attribute, the attribute tags are without any meaning. It is a container without "graphic semantics". So I think that in this case, it is understandable to have such a "naked Q".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An attributed string does not have "a font size". The used font is an attribute, which can vary over the String. Look at your Q: There are two different fonts in one paragraph. (One for the usual text and one for the keywords.)

Therefore you can only ask for the existing attributes (including font) at a specific location. I. e. [`- attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000166-SW9) does this job for you. The attribute key for the font is `NSFontAttributeName`. If yo do not find this key in the attributes dictionary, it is Helvetica(Neue), 12 pt.